# Why would netcat work fine from commandline but fail in a jenkins build?

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, netcat

I have a shell script running in a build server, that kicks off a huge virtual machine and then waits for a message on a port with:

```
nc -vv -l -p 9090
```

The huge virtual machine runs a super-complicated script which includes the following simple statement when it completes its task:

```
echo Completed | nc -vv -w10 $TARGET_IP 9090
```

Where TARGET_IP is a statically configured IP address of the build server.

This all works fine when I initiate the script on the command line.

However, when I incorporate the very same script into a Jenkins build, on the very same machine, the `nc` call in the script on the huge vm fails with:

```
/var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt: line 11: echo: write error: Broken pipe
```

What could cause this strange difference in behaviour?

Environment is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on AWS EC2.

Comment: I'd generally expect there to be an error from `nc`, in addition to the error from `echo`.

Comment: That said -- is SELinux enabled on this machine? Do you know that the service is *allowed* to open outbound connections? (iptables too can enforce per-user restrictions on outbound traffic). And make sure your `nc` isn't coming from somewhere in the user's `PATH` but not in that used by your Jenkins build.

Comment: BTW, if I were debugging this myself, I'd probably use [Sysdig](https://sysdig.com/opensource/sysdig/) to trace the details of the failure.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not currently working on this project, so I can't check right now, but is it possible (assuming SELinux is enabled) that `nc -vv -l -p 9090` would silently fail to listen on the port? A key difference between the Jenkins and the Non-Jenkins execution is that the former is started by the jenkins user, while the latter is started by `root`. The VM (9090 connection initiation side) is literally identical either way since it's rebuilt and launched by the same script.